# How to pass data in url using cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I wanted to now if there is a way to pass a simple string inside url and cakephp some how put it inside one of the inputs of my form without any code writing on view side? 
I tried calling this->set("bla","bla"); the field name is bla
but nothing changed in view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood the question you want to have something like this:

in the url you have something like:

```
http://yourserver.com/controller/action?search=string
```

and you want to put this "string" in the search field, right?

Then let's imagine that your field's name is data[search_field]. (I am skipping the model, because for my example it's not needed, but it's possible the name to be data[Model][search_field]).

Then in your controller's action you have to do following:

```
$this->data['search_string'] = $this->params['url']['search'];
```

Comment: Only one thing is missing, if form encounters a validation error after submit, this will fire a warning I needed to add the flollowing:  if (isset($this->params['url']['subject']))
  {
   echo $form->hidden('subject',array('default'=>$this->params['url']['subject']));
  }
  else
  {
   echo $form->hidden('subject');
  }

Answer (score 2):

You can pass values in the url by using html helper. Try:

```
echo $this->Html->link('View Some Page', array(
    'controller' => 'yourController',
    'action' => 'view',
    1, // id
    '?' => array('yourField' => 'valueToPass'))
);
```

Comment: I did not understand your question. If you build a link using html helper you can pass any value of any parameter to any page you want.

Comment: Yes yes this is obvious, will cake know to put the data in the view field?

Comment: Try to do that. If it does not work then you will need to catch the value from url in the view (`$this->params['yourField']`) and input it to the field as default value, for example http://book.cakephp.org/view/1402/options-default.